# Python regular expression, print all special character from a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, special-characters

Input :- "ABCD&EFab^cdef12%3450"

Output expected :- &^%

What was tried

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+')
print(pattern.search("ABCD&EFab^cdef12%3450"))
```

Actual output:- prints only the first occurrence of metacharacter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try findall instead of search

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+')
print(pattern.findall("ABCD&EFab^cdef12%3450"))
```

Comment: Thank you Craeft, I was wondering if we have any regular expression based solution rather using findall which is an python based solution.

Comment: findall repeatedly applies the regex to the string.  There aren't any other functions in python which do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of search which returns the first occurrence of pattern and not entire. 
The syntax of sub is :
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, max=0). Omit max=0, a pattern is the pattern to be replaced with repl and string is the text.

```
print(re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]',"","ABCD&EFab^cdef12%3450"))
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev, I was wondering if we have any regular expression based solution rather using substitute which looks like a indirect solution or kind of hack solution.